# How may I completely disable all Emacs' default bindings to the Fn keys (F2 - F12)?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm willing to allow help to remain on `F1`, but I don't want any of Emacs default bindings on any of the other `Fn` keys.  If you must know why, it's because all keyboards made in the last 20 years are garbage, and I'm done putting up with "accidentally" ending up in 2C mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
(global-set-key [f2] nil)
```

will 'unbind' `f2`, so you don't need to worry about accidentally entering 2C mode.

There's no general way to disable all the function keys, but you can rebind them however you like, just like other keys. F5-F9 are reserved for user's to bind as they like, so they shouldn't be bound to anything already. Some package developers ignore this recommendation though.

Comment: Nope, still getting 2C mode every time I press `F2`.  I don't know how g-s-k is supposed to work though.  Do I have to do something else to make it take effect immediately?

Comment: I assume you put that line in your .emacs, saved the file, and then restarted Emacs? That's all that should be needed. If it doesn't work we'll need more details about your setup to debug